# Why I am getting the below error while I am trying to open a macros excel workbook in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, vba

```
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.AskToUpdateLinks = False
xl.EnableEvents = True
print("befire opening excel")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=filledValSheet)
wb.Application.Run("Value_Trades")
print("Valuation completed for ", filledValSheet)
```

Error:

```
[2019-10-26 19:22:03,218: WARNING/MainProcess] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DVC-AMP\BE\dvcApp\valuation.py", line 93, in valuateProduct
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=filledValSheet)
  File "C:\Users\AMEER~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.6\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x8\Workbooks.py", line 78, in Open
    , Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: Your file might be corrupted. Test the following. ① Create a new Excel file in the exactly same folder and use the same code to open it. Does that work? ② Open your file in Excel and check if it asks you to repair it.

Comment: Yeah, when I am opening the file it showing.file needs to be repaired to open.when I click yes it shows ,repaired content : cell information contains from x1/worksheets/sheet10.XML part

Comment: I dunno how to find particular cell which is damaged or how to repair

Comment: Other files opening in same folder but this perticulr file getting corrupted

Comment: Once your file is corrupt it stays corrupt in most cases (even if Excel tells you it could be repaired). The only really clean way is to get a non-corrupted file is to start a completely new one and copy over values and formulas only (no formattings!). • I also recommend to save the file in the binary `xlsb` format instead of `xlsm` or `xlsx` format. The binary format is known to be much more stable (especially on heavy data sheets) while the `xlsm`/`xlsx` format are known to easily cause corruption issues.

Comment: Can I save it in xlsb even I have macros in it ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can. The binary format can contain macros.